# Why is the following java code converted to jasmin like this?

Tags: java, assembly, compilation, jasmin

I have the following sample java class that I want to convert to jasmin:

```
public class JavaModel {
public int main() {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 5;
    if(a < b || a < b || a < b || a < b) {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
    return 0;
}
}
```

When I convert it to jasmin with:

```
javac src/test/java/JavaModel.java
javap -c src/test/java/JavaModel.class > src/test/java/JavaModelOutput
```

I get the following output:

```
Compiled from "JavaModel.java"
public class JavaModel {
public JavaModel();
Code:
   0: aload_0
   1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4: return

public int main();
Code:
   0: iconst_0
   1: istore_1
   2: iconst_5
   3: istore_2
   4: iload_1
   5: iload_2
   6: if_icmplt     24
   9: iload_1
  10: iload_2
  11: if_icmplt     24
  14: iload_1
  15: iload_2
  16: if_icmplt     24
  19: iload_1
  20: iload_2
  21: if_icmpge     32
  24: getstatic                       
  27: ldc                             
  29: invokevirtual                  
  32: iconst_0
  33: ireturn
  }
```

Why is line 21 converted like this? Shouldn't it be the same as 6,11,16?

Answer (score 0):

```
  21: if_icmpge     32
```

If this line were instead:

```
  21: if_icmplt     24
```

then it would jump to line 24 if the `icmplt` is true, but it would do the same if it were false. Effectively, it would be a no-op.

Answer (score 0):

The last compare/branch in a chain of conditions has to skip over the `if` body if it shouldn't run.  All the others in the chain of `||` short-circuit evaluation are jumping *to* the `if` body if it *should* run.

As Andy's answer points out, `if() goto next_line` is a NOP, going the same place whether the condition is true or false.

You could have the last if_cmpxx jump also be a conditional jump to the `if` body *if* you put the `if` body out-of-line, so the fall-through is into the return 0.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. I would like to programme a Java-Jasmin converter myself. Do you have any tips on how to best evaluate such && || concatenations. It confuses me a bit when these concatenations become very long. Maybe there is an algorithm?

Comment: @flo: It's not specific to Java bytecode (represented by Jasmin assembly); it's the same problem compilers targets real CPU assembly languages face.  (And of course `javac` compiling directly to bytecode; `javac` is open-source so you could dig into it if you really wanted, although I expect the code isn't very readable).  You can decompose `if(x || y || z)` by figuring out the order of operations (operator precedence and `()`), and peeling off conditions one at a time, turning each one into separate if-goto operations, either to the actual if body or to code that checks more conditions.

Comment: @flo: If you want to learn to write a compiler (parsing and code-gen), there are textbooks on the subject.  The dragon book is highly regarded, although I haven't read it or any other compiler textbook.